# Как убрать скролл в мобильной версии если все таки необходимо спрятать часть блока, чтобы при нажатии он появлялся полностью?

Tags: html, css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка

Получается, что правая сторона, содержащая скрытый блок в мобильной версии имеет скрол. Можно ли как то поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну суть в том, что контейнеру даёте overflow: hidden;

```js
document.querySelector('.block_hidden').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle('open');
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block_hidden {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
   position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.block_hidden.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block_hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть отрицательным значением увести картинку с глаз не получится?)

Comment: что значит отрицательным  значением ? чем не нравится transform? он берёт проценты от своей ширины. тогда вам всё равно какая ширина блока. Ну если хотите можете убрать transform, и задать right: -200px(в случае если известна ширина - 400px), и при open давать right: 0

Comment: Или что вы имеете ввиду. уточните

Comment: Пробую задать overflow: hidden для блока, в котором находится изображение - не выходит - на мобильном не уходит сдвиг влево.

Comment: http://oliver.sliding.com.ua/

Comment: не тому... вот этому блоку row row-contacts-mobile, или его дочернему col (.row.row-contacts-mobil .col). я бы выбрал первый вариант, просто .row.row-contacts-mobil

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало)